# rails returning the object not a list of one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Alright so i have a scope to find the model with the position equal to the parameter:

```
class EatTile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :link, :map, :name, :num_votes, :position, :price, :rating

  scope :pos, lambda{|position| {:conditions => ["position = ?", position]}}
end
```

In my controller i have the following to get the tiles i need:

```
@tiles = EatTile.where("position > 0 AND position < 20")
```

I was thinking that I would be able to call something like this in my view if I wanted to get the name of the tile with position 1:

```
@tiles.pos(1).name
```

Instead I have to include "first" between the pos call and name. Is this the best way to do this? I am new to rails and don't want to go about doing things wrong early.

Also is it faster to do it the way i have above, or would it be better to just have this in my view:

```
EatTile.pos(1).first.name
```

I think the first way i did it is more correct because it narrows down the query first, but am not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to type `first` because the result of the query is an array (generally speaking). Just imagine that you could have several records that are matched your condition, it will look ridiculous to not retrieve one object from array and call method on it, isn't it?

About array. When you typed the `@tiles.pos(1)` line actually you've got the instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You can check it by typing `@tiles.pos(1).class`. Having Relation object allows us to chain with another queries in purpose to produce one SQL query to database at the end.

UPDATE:

It might look that the solution could be like this:

```
scope :pos, lambda { |position| where(:position => position).first }
```

But it can lead to a future mistakes, because the purpose of scope is to be chainable with another queries, calling the method `first` will kill the lazy functinality.

I think the solution could be is just add method:

```
def self.get_pos(position)
  pos(position).first
end
```

So the you can use it like this

```
EatTile.get_pos(1).name
```

Comment: right, i understand that i could be grabbing more than one and thats why i have to call first, i just thought there might be a better, or cleaner, way to do this. But if not i am happy leaving it the way i have it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could define custom class method `pos`:

```
class EatTile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.pos(position)
    where(:position => position).first
  end
end
```

It'll make possible to use `@tiles.pos(1).name`.